# Capture play event from mediaplayer on webview?

Tags: android, video, webview, android-mediaplayer

I need access to media controls of video player embedded in webview html page. Webpage is a client web page and cannot be modified to achieve javascript interaction.
Basically I need the video download url, tried using shouldOverrideUrlLoading() of webview client, it doesn't work for flash players on webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you play the video in videoview then you can control using mediaPlayer.
But in case of videoPlayer embedded in webview I don't think you'll have access to control the player.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I came to the same conclusion, However is there a way to read the play button action and get the stream url?